# Creating shopping cart object with SESSION

Tags: php, session, shopping-cart

How should I create my shopping cart object without overwriting the session/object each time?  My code below doesn't  work properly because when I've added items each time I click the submit button it start from scratch and overwrites the basket.

See live version here: http://www.animportantdate.co.uk/home/products.php

My code is:

```
 session_start();
 include('oopCart.php');

 $basket = new shoppingCart($_SESSION['cart']);

 if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
      $id = $_POST['id'];
      $qty = $_POST['qty'];
      $basket->addItem($id, $qty);
 }
 ?>
   <form method="POST" action="products.php">
<input type="hidden" value="dog" name="id">
<input type="hidden" value="10" name="qty">
<input type="submit" value="buy 10 dogs" name="submit">
   </form>

  <?php
  echo '<BR>items in basket: '. $basket->countItems();
  echo '<BR>Total number of dogs (201): '. $basket->numberOfProduct('dog');
  echo '<BR>is dog in basket? '. $basket->isInCart('dog');
  ?>
```

edit:  i've added some of the shoppingcart class below.  I should mention that when I create the object and test all the methods it contains in the same php file it works fine. Thus the methods all work well. It's just the instantiating that's causing me problems.

```
  class ShoppingCart{

protected $id;
protected $qty;
protected $cart = array();

// constructor accepts the session variable to create cart object
function __construct($cart=""){
   $this->cart = $cart;
}

function addItem($id, $qty=1){
    if (($this->isInCart($id))  == false ){ 
        $this->cart[$id] = array( 'id' => $id, 'qty' => $qty);
    } else{
        $this->cart[$id]['qty'] += $qty;            
    }
}

function isInCart($id){
    $inCart=false;
    if ($this->cart[$id]){
        return $inCart=true;
                break;
    }   
    return $inCart;
}

public function isEmpty(){
    return (empty($this->cart));
}

function countUniqueItems(){
    if ($this->isEmpty()==false){
        foreach($this->cart as $item){
            if($item['id']){
                $uniqueItems++;
            }
        }
    }
    return $uniqueItems;

}
```

}

Comment: It looks like the problem is in your `shoppingCart` class. Could you post the code for that? Or if it's very long, then just post the constructor function and any other methods in the class that the constructor depends on.

Comment: BTW the standard convention for classes in PHP is that they start with an uppercase letter, e.g. `class ShoppingCart` instead of `class shoppingCart`. Best to follow this convention unless you have a strong reason not to.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your session settings are misconfigured. If the session path within the php.ini file is incorrect it's possible that the session is not actually being saved if you have error reporting set to 0.

Check your php.ini sessions section.